# Is it possible to wire an aux cable directly to the radio wires under the dash of an automobile?

Tags: electrical, toyota, audio

Two problems:
   1) I don't have a car stereo installed because the harnesses don't match
   2) Due to my destructive curiosity, I refuse to buy a  $10 adapter

So I want to know if there is a way to wire the aux cable directly to the wires under the dash... Thanks

Comment: To recap, you want to connect the line-level output of a phone/mp3 player directly to the speakers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short NO.

The speaker outputs are not compatible with line inputs on say a subwoofer amplifier. The speaker output puts out too much power and has the wrong impedance. Connecting this to an amplifier will likely damage the amplifier.

In long Yes.

This requires a .... wait for it ... a $10 adapter.

http://www.crutchfield.com/p_142LOC80/Scosche-LOC80.html?tp=2001

The adapter converts speaker outputs to line outputs.

Comment: A $10 adapter ... who'd a thunk it :o)

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. The question states the car doesn't have a stereo installed, so can't possibly have speaker-level signals.

Comment: @Hobbes I interpreted this as "The car does not have an aftermarket stereo installed". That is the stereo lacks aux outputs. Further interpretation suggests that the factory stereo is still there because the OP wants to hook up to something.